# Why isn't sox recording anything?

Tags: audio, recording, sox

I have an RTL-SDR radio receiver which outputs streaming data to stdout. I can listen to the audio with this command:

```
$ rtl_fm -M wbfm -f 96.5M | play -r 32k -t raw -e s -b 16 -c 1 -V1 -
```

As you can see, rtl_fm outputs a stream of samples consisting of 16-bit signed integers at a sample rate of 32 kHz.

Now, I would like to record this audio using sox, so I tried

```
$ rtl_fm -M wbfm -f 96.5M -g 25 | rec -e s -b 16 -r 32000 out.wav
```

I'm getting a wav file alright, but it's just empty - all the values are zero. I tried

```
$ rtl_fm -M wbfm -f 96.5M -g 25 | rec -e s -b 16 -r 32000 -t raw out.wav
```

But that only got me a file, Audacity didn't recognise as wav. If I import it as raw data, it's still all zeros.

Like I wrote, when I run the play command, I have audio, but when I record, I get nothing.

For what it's worth, here's the output from the record command:

```
$ rtl_fm -M wbfm -f 96.5M -g 25 | rec -e s -b 16 -r 32000 -c 1 out.wav
Found 1 device(s):
0:  Realtek, RTL2838UHIDIR, SN: 00000001

rec WARN alsa: can't encode 0-bit Unknown or not applicable
Using device 0: Generic RTL2832U OEM

Input File     : 'default' (alsa)
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 32000
Precision      : 16-bit
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM

In:0.00% 00:00:00.00 [00:00:00.00] Out:0     [      |      ]        Clip:0    Detached kernel driver
In:0.00% 00:00:00.26 [00:00:00.00] Out:0     [      |      ]        Clip:0    Found Rafael Micro R820T tuner
In:0.00% 00:00:00.51 [00:00:00.00] Out:8.19k [      |      ]        Clip:0    Tuner gain set to 25.40 dB.
Tuned to 96771000 Hz.
oversampling input by: 6x.
Oversampling output by: 1x.
Buffer size: 8.03ms
Exact sample rate is: 1020000.026345 Hz
Create UDP thread
Created UDP thread
Allocating 15 zero-copy buffers
Main socket started! :-) Tuning enabled on UDP/6020 
Sampling at 1020000 S/s.
Output at 170000 Hz.
In:0.00% 00:00:09.22 [00:00:00.00] Out:287k  [      |      ]        Clip:0    ^CSignal caught, exiting!

User cancel, exiting...
In:0.00% 00:00:09.47 [00:00:00.00] Out:295k  [      |      ]        Clip:0    
Aborted.
Signal caught, exiting!
Reattached kernel driver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace `rec` with `ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 32k -ac 1 -i pipe: file.wav`

`ffmpeg -formats | grep PCM` in case I'm wrong.

Your output

> rec WARN alsa: can't encode 0-bit Unknown or not applicable

might indicate you're actually recording from an actual microphone (which I presume is not connected).

Comment: It works - amazing. I didn't know ffmpeg could do that. Why use sox when you can use ffmpeg! Thanks!